# Speed up two nested for loops and multiple if statements pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data which looks like the following. I have been busy with this code for some days and can't crack it..

```
ID  | Time     | Min_time | Max_time | Status | Date        |
1   | 15:32:20 | 15:32:20 | 15:33:04 | High   | 01/01/2019  |
1   | 15:32:30 | 15:32:20 | 15:33:04 | High   | 01/01/2019  |
1   | 15:33:04 | 15:32:20 | 15:33:04 | High   | 01/01/2019  |
2   | 15:32:10 | 15:32:10 | 15:40:05 | High   | 01/01/2019  |
2   | 15:40:05 | 15:32:10 | 15:40:05 | High   | 01/01/2019  |
3   | 17:20:04 | 17:20:04 | 17:29:20 | Low    | 02/01/2019  |
3   | 17:25:10 | 17:20:04 | 17:29:20 | Low    | 02/01/2019  |
3   | 17:29:20 | 17:20:04 | 17:29:20 | Low    | 02/01/2019  |
4   | 15:32:30 | 15:32:30 | 15:40:08 | High   | 01/01/2019  |
4   | 15:32:38 | 15:32:30 | 15:40:08 | High   | 01/01/2019  |
4   | 15:40:08 | 15:32:30 | 15:40:08 | High   | 01/01/2019  |
5   | 15:35:10 | 15:35:10 | 15:36:08 | Low    | 01/01/2019  |
5   | 15:36:08 | 15:35:10 | 15:36:08 | Low    | 01/01/2019  |
..  |          |          |          |        |
```

I would like to find the IDs where

1. the status of the order is not equal (so when it's High then it
   should find the IDs with 'Low') AND
2. The date is on the same day AND
3. The min time falls in between the min and max time of the order on the other side.

So for point 3: For example "15:32:30" of ID 4 falls in between the min_time and max_time of ID 2.

My code looks like this now :

```
dict_results = {"ID_outer_loop":[], "ID_inner_loop":[]}
for key, value in df.iterrows():
    for key2, value2 in df.iterrows():
        if value["Min_time"] > value2["Min_time"]:
            if value["Min_time"] < value2["Max_time"]:
                if value["Date"] == value2["Date"]:
                    if value["Status"] != value2["Status"]:
                        dict_results["ID_outer_loop"].append(value["ID"])
                        dict_results["ID_inner_loop"].append(value2["ID"])
```

How would I speed up this process for 200k rows?

Comment: You might want to take a look at list comprehension and list processing functions such as `filter`.

Comment: Are you up for using pandas? A groupby on id would probably fix most of your concerns

Comment: I'll have a look at it, but my python is not that great unfortunately..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for producing the pairwise row comparison and then `filter` according to the specified criteria:

```
import itertools as it
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
valid_pairs = filter(
    lambda x: x[0][1] != x[1][1] and x[0][2] == x[1][2] and x[1][3] <= x[0][3] <= x[1][4],
    it.product(zip(df['ID'], df['Status'], df['Date'], df['Min_time'], df['Max_time']), repeat=2)
)
valid_ids = ((x[0][0], x[1][0]) for x in valid_pairs)
ID_outer_loop, ID_inner_loop = zip(*valid_ids)
```

Creating only unique ID pairs can be achieved by using `valid_ids = set(valid_ids)`. If there are many duplicate `valid_pairs` this can save a significant amount of memory since all the previous steps are lazily computed and only evaluated when adding to the set (discarding duplicates).

Another way that shortcuts on the first match per ID pair is to first `groupby('ID')`, then pair up the groups and finally make sure not to compute beyond the first match via `any`:

```
valid_pairs = filter(
    lambda g: any(x[0][0] != x[1][0] and x[0][1] == x[1][1] and x[1][2] <= x[0][2] <= x[1][3]
                  for x in zip(zip(g[0][1]['Status'], g[0][1]['Date'], g[0][1]['Min_time']),
                               zip(g[1][1]['Status'], g[1][1]['Date'], g[1][1]['Min_time'], g[1][1]['Max_time']))),
    it.product(df.groupby('ID'), repeat=2)
)
```

Comment: I will try this out a_guest

Comment: This seems to be memory efficient, but as can be seen from the test results, it blows up the data by looping it a couple of times. Is there a way to group the results or just loop once and when found then stop processing for those orders? If you can provide that, then I will mark this as the answer. Result look like this:
(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5) (2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4)

Comment: @milky I don't understand what you mean by that. Your example data frame contains duplicate `ID`s and multiple such pairs match your criteria. That's why you see duplicate pairs in the output. Specifically each of the `5` matches all `2` and `4` and thus you the pairs are actually as follows (underscore suffix denotes occurrence count): `[(5_0, 2_0), (5_0, 2_1), (5_0, 4_0), (5_0, 4_1), (5_0, 4_2), (5_1, 2_0), (5_1, 2_1), (5_1, 4_0), (5_1, 4_1), (5_1, 4_2)]`.

Comment: Note that in general the output might contain `(x_j, y_k)` and `(y_k, x_j)` but this are by no means duplicates according to your criteria (since `<=` does not commute). Further note that in case you consider these pairs duplicates then the check for `x['Min_time'] <= y['Min_time']` is redundant because either way it will hold. Could you please clarify how you intend to handle these situations?

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible to get the distinct IDs where it matches on, so:
[5,5] - [2,4] so that I can convert it to a pandas dataframe with pd.DataFrame(zip(list())) functionality

Comment: @milky Sure just use another `valid_ids = set(valid_ids)` or if order doesn't matter then `valid_ids = set(map(tuple, map(sorted, valid_ids)))`.

Comment: You should add it to your answer, it seems like the `valid_ids = set(valid_ids)` takes care of the Memory issue. I tried it out on 50000 rows and ran for about 650 seconds.

Comment: @milky I also added another way that shortcuts on the first match per group. It involves an additional `groupby` beforehand so judging on performance is difficult but maybe you can give it a try and comment on the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Numpy outer products and broadcasting for the pairwise comparisons:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
mask = np.logical_and(
    np.not_equal.outer(df['Status'], df['Status']),
    np.logical_and(
        np.equal.outer(df['Date'], df['Date']),
        np.logical_and(
            df['Min_time'].values[:, None] <= df['Min_time'].values[None, :],
            df['Min_time'].values[None, :] <= df['Max_time'].values[:, None])))
indices = mask.nonzero()
ID_outer_loop = df['ID'].iloc[indices[0]]
ID_inner_loop = df['ID'].iloc[indices[1]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, this produces a memory error for 200K rows. Also, it does not speed up the process really.

Comment: @milky Since the memory consumption is N**2 this won't work for larger data frames. As long as they fit in memory though I would be surprised if this method was not significantly faster than the doubly nested loops over `iterrows`. Did you do any benchmarks on a subset of the data frame? If so, would you be willing to share the results and/or data?